# How can I select the surrounding values into the NULLs of a column in SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two columns: a date and a numeric value. I want to have this table "diluted" in a way that it will have a new entry for every day between a start and end date (basically the list of days) and have the aforementioned numeric value set not just for it's corresponding date, but also to the surrounding newly created dates as well.
I have no idea what the proper approach in SQL is for a problem like this (PostgreSQL preferably).

So for an input:

- I have two dates: start date and end date
- A table with two columns: a date and a value

The dates:

```
 start: 2023-04-01
 end:   2023-04-10
```

The table:

```
 date       | value
--------------------
 2023-04-03 | 1000
 2023-04-06 | 500
 2023-04-08 | 2500
```

Step 1: Have a result table that has an entry for all days between (inclusively) the start and end dates.

```
 date
------------
 2023-04-01
 2023-04-02
 2023-04-03
 2023-04-04
 2023-04-05
 2023-04-06
 2023-04-07
 2023-04-08
 2023-04-09
 2023-04-10
```

Step 2: Add a column with the value that already exists in the input table.

```
 date       | value
--------------------
 2023-04-01 | [NULL]
 2023-04-02 | [NULL]
 2023-04-03 | 1000
 2023-04-04 | [NULL]
 2023-04-05 | [NULL]
 2023-04-06 | 500
 2023-04-07 | [NULL]
 2023-04-08 | 2500
 2023-04-09 | [NULL]
 2023-04-10 | [NULL]
```

Step 3 (What I'm currently struggling with): Fill in the NULL values with the surrounding values. The rules are:

- If the value is null, find the PREVIOUS closest non-NULL value, and set it's value
- If the value is at the start, or all previous values are NULL, find the NEXT closest non-NULL value, and set it's value

```
 date       | value 
--------------------
 2023-04-01 | 1000
 2023-04-02 | 1000
 2023-04-03 | 1000
 2023-04-04 | 1000
 2023-04-05 | 1000
 2023-04-06 | 500
 2023-04-07 | 500
 2023-04-08 | 2500
 2023-04-09 | 2500
 2023-04-10 | 2500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following demonstrates a method for producing the specified results:

```
WITH test_values(
  test_date,
  test_value
) AS (
  VALUES ('2023-03-31'::date, 1),
         ('2023-04-03'::date, 1000),
         ('2023-04-06'::date, 500),
         ('2023-04-08'::date, 2500),
         ('2023-04-11'::date, 9999)
),
test_range(start_date, end_date) AS (
    VALUES ('2023-04-01'::date, '2023-04-10'::date)
)
SELECT
  GENERATE_SERIES(CASE WHEN LAG(test_values.test_date) OVER (ORDER BY test_values.test_date) IS NULL THEN test_range.start_date ELSE test_values.test_date END,
                  LEAD(test_values.test_date - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 1, test_range.end_date) OVER (ORDER BY test_values.test_date),
                  INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS test_date,
  test_values.test_value
  FROM
    test_range JOIN test_values ON test_values.test_date BETWEEN test_range.start_date AND test_range.end_date
 ORDER BY test_date;
```

I've renamed the columns `DATE` and `VALUE` to `test_date` and `test_value` to avoid using keywords as column identifiers. I've also added rows with dates immediately prior to and following those in the test range to expose off-by-one defects in the query.

For each row in `test_values`, the query generates rows for dates on or after the row's `test_date` up until the day prior to the next `test_date` in the set. The first row is a special case: if there isn't a preceding row by date, then `start_date` is substituted for `test_date`.